# How can I change YouTrack installation folder?

Tags: youtrack

I setup YouTrack in windows server 2012 r2 with MSI package on c:\YouTrack but now I want to change the folder to: e:\YouTrack how I can do it?

Comment: probably re-installing... and using the same data folder as before (don't forget a backup, stored in a safe spot)

Comment: Thanks Carlos, it can be a good solution

Comment: also don't forget to make backup and save at some secure (different) location

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to change YouTrack installation folder is **reinstalling** YouTrack.

There is an article [Restore-MSI-Installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Restore-MSI-Installation.html#restore-from-database-backup) in YouTrack documentation describing how to do that.

Briefly the steps are as follows:

1. Create backup and store that in some secure location (see [Backup Database Now](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Back-Up-the-Database.html))
2. [Uninstall YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/uninstall-youtrack-msi.html) (the simplest way would be opening `Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall` and removing YouTrack there)

   - Check that folder `c:\YouTrack` was completely removed after YouTrack uninstalled. Remove the folder manually if something left there.
   - Remove content of `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\YouTrack` (YouTrack stores application data there by default). Make sure that your backup file is stored outside that folder.
3. Run MSI installer and complete MSI Wizard choosing new installation directory (`e:\YouTrack`)

   - You may install the same YouTrack version as well as a newer one (though if you use commercial license and choose to install a newer YouTrack version, it may require to renew the license if its upgrade period has expired).
   - MSI Wizard may ask you what to do with the old configs if any would be detected. Choose recommended option to discard them - actual configs will be restored from backup on the next steps.
4. Configuration Wizard would be opened in browser right after MSI Wizard finished installing YouTrack package.
5. Choose option Upgrade in Configuration Wizard and select backup file there (make sure local user `./JetBrainsYouTrack` has full access to the folder with backup file)
6. [Optional] Customize locations where YouTrack stores its application data (DB, logs, backups, temp). By default those are stored inside `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\YouTrack`.

   - Make sure that local user `./JetBrainsYouTrack` have access to the selected custom folders (access to the default location `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\YouTrack` is configured automatically by MSI installer)
   - Data folder should be empty. If custom data directory was used (by uninstalled YouTrack instance) and you'd like to keep using that, then remove all files left there and choose that folder in Wizard. Database will be restored to the chosen data directory from backup.
7. Complete configuration Wizard and wait until YouTrack is started.